# Кириллица в json_encode

Tags: json, php

Функция `json_encode` кириллицу utf-8 кодирует в виде `\u....`. Как её заставить  кодировать символы "как есть"?

Примечание: не используя второй параметр `json_encode` и mb-функции.

Comment: У-ха-ха, тоже только хотел создать такой же вопрос, т.к. появилась такая-же проблема (json и кириллица)!

Comment: А смысл ? Пусть себе кодирует... без проблем "\u..." читаюьтся  JS-ом.
Думаю, что Вам не в эту сторону смотреть нужно :)

Comment: Ребят а как правильно вобще по стандарту так сказать?))) для апи адроида)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Пришлось писать свою функцию. Надеюсь, не сильно накосячил?

```
function normJsonStr($str){
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/i', create_function('$m', 'return chr(hexdec($m[1])-1072+224);'), $str);
    return iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str);
}
```

Comment: А разве при этом json остаётся валидным? В нём вроде по стандарту экранирование юникода должно быть?

Comment: @Isaev конкретно код в ответе не проверял, но JSON всё подряд экранировать не требует, неэкранированная кириллица это вполне валидно

Comment: букву `ё` не распознает

Comment: @Abmin попробуй
function fixBadUnicodeForJson($str) {$str = preg_replace("/\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})/e", 'chr(hexdec("$1")).chr(hexdec("$2")).chr(hexdec("$3")).chr(hexdec("$4"))', $str);$str = preg_replace("/\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})/e", 'chr(hexdec("$1")).chr(hexdec("$2")).chr(hexdec("$3"))', $str);$str = preg_replace("/\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})/e", 'chr(hexdec("$1")).chr(hexdec("$2"))', $str);$str = preg_replace("/\\\\u00([0-9a-f]{2})/e", 'chr(hexdec("$1"))', $str);return $str;}

Answer (score 60):

В PHP начиная с версии 5.4.0 появился флаг `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` и все стало намного проще:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: > Примечание: не используя второй параметр json_encode и mb-функции.

и вопросу  сто лет

Comment: @cyborgg4655 а как правильно по стандарту так сказать?

Comment: @FORTRAN, если у вас PHP версии больше 5.4, то предпочитительнее вариант с JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, до версии 5.4, придется воспользоваться вариантом ling.

Answer (score 4):

в начале файла добавь

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Указывать `Content-Type` свой, по ситуации

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что это поможет?

Comment: @0xdb без указания заголовка с кодировкой в файле, функция `json_encode` у меня кодирует кириллицу как у автора в виде `\u...`

Answer (score 3):

Предположу, что данные идут с базы данных. В таком случае при подключении к базе данных необходимо указать кодировку подключения — UTF-8.

```
"mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8"
```

Answer (score 3):

Искал как решить проблему, в итоге заработало когда добавил к json_encode флаг - JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
и сменил кодировку при выводе

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: А что делать, если это консольное приложение?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. http://php.net/releases/NEWS_5_4_0_beta1.txt

> - Improved JSON extension:   . Added new json_encode() option
>   JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE. FR #53946.
>       (Alexander, Gwynne)

Comment: Да, о флаге я в курсе. Также видел решение без флага, но с mb-функцией. Мне не подходит ни то, ни то.

Comment: По этому и ответил "никак". Только использовать реализации на php. Например из Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рекурсивная функция, которая может конвертировать в UTF-8 все строки в массиве и объекте:

```
public function utf8ize($data) {
    if (is_array($data))
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            $data[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);

    else if(is_object($data))
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            $data->$key = $this->utf8ize($value);

    else
        return utf8_encode($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Также json_last_error() может быть полезным в отладке json_encode()/json_encode() функций.