# Кривая кодировка в json_encode с русскими символами

Tags: кодировка, json_encode, php

```
$json = array('name' => 'Руслан', 'last_name' => 'Садыхов');
return json_encode($json);
```

Возвращаются вместо имени и фамилии подобные символы: **\u0420\u0443\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043d**

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: json_decode

Comment: @KryDos, напишите, пожалуйста код. Иначе json_decode($json); отдаёт пустоту.

Comment: @ModaL, написал

Comment: `\u0420` -- `Р`, `\u0443` -- `у` и т.д.

Comment: @alexlz, понял :D Придётся так, думал есть способ легче)

Comment: Как так? В C есть wctomb/mbtowc, а вот в php -- не знаю...

     <?php
     $unicodeChar = '\u0420\u0443\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043d';
     echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
     ?>

     Руслан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Кириллица в json_encode**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37998/php-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-json_encode)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько старые посты, но может кому пригодится это : `\u0420\u0443\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043d` json кодировка, она должна быть такой, на jquery делаем `var result= JSON.parse('\u0420\u0443\...');` получаем человекопонятный массив

Comment: 1) Это не jquery; 2) Это не работает